# What should be the docx template to put two XML fields in one column using OpenXmlPowerTools

Tags: c#, .net-core, openxml-powertools

In my project we are generating reports using `OpenXmlPowerTools` by passing XML to `DocumentAssembler.AssembleDocument` method.

Everything works fine. Currently this is the table template in my `.docx` file

[image]

Now, I have added one more field to the `rpt_ProformaInvoiceReportResult`, but I do not want to show this new field in a new column in the table but in the existing column `Equipment Number`, so I tried this,

[image]

But this does not work. It never shows the `SystemNumber` value.

It does work when I create a new column and put this new field to that new column.

So looks like the template only binds one Xml field to one column.

Is there any way to achieve what I am trying to do?

That is putting `FullEquipmentNumber` and `SystemNumber` fields in one single column